# How to loop through table view that has custom cells and get information from the custom cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hey guys I'm having an issue with an `UITableView`. 
[image]

I am making a chat application but there are duplicate cells for whatever reason. So I want to loop through all **visible** cells, and get the properties like time and name to allow me to delete any duplicates. But I get the error:

> Cast from 'UserCell' to unrelated type 'Array' always
>   fails

How can I fix this issue or is there a better way to loop through a table view with custom cells?

What I'm trying to do:

```
    func deleteDuplicateTableCells(){
    let cells = self.messagesTableView.visibleCells as! UserCell as! Array<UITableViewCell>

    for cell in cells {
        // get .name and .timestamp from cell

    }


}
```

Here is the important part of the `UserCell` class:

```
class UserCell : UITableViewCell {

var message : Message? {
 didSet{



    if let id = message?.chatPartnerId{

        let ref = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(id()!)
        ref.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
            {
                self.textLabel?.text = dict["username"] as? String

                if let profileImageUrl = dict["pic"] as? String {
                    self.profileImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(urlString: profileImageUrl)
                }
            }



        }, withCancel: nil)

    }

    detailTextLabel?.text = message?.text

    let timeInt = message?.timestamp?.numberValue

    if let seconds = timeInt?.doubleValue{
        let timeStampDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: seconds)

        let dateformat = DateFormatter()
        dateformat.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a"
        timeLabel.text = dateformat.string(from: timeStampDate as Date)


    }

}
}
```

Comment: You don't loop through the cells to get their data. The cells don't contain your data. The data model used by your table view's dataSource contains the data. At least that is how it is supposed to work.

Comment: So the real issue is the duplicate cells? If you post more information about your data model and your data source methods, someone might be able to fix your real issue.

Comment: Remember the table is the presentation later only.  Your uitableviewdatasource is the place where you should evaluate your data. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource

Comment: How would i loop through the dataSource then? Im kinda new to this thanks for all the help guys

Comment: @rmaddy ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Update your question with your `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt` methods.

Answer (score 0):

The way your trying to get your visible cells is a bit off, try this:

`guard let cells = tableView.visibleCells as? [UserCell] else { return }`

and then do whatever you want to do with them

`if cells.map {}... // or whatever`

I do have to agree with the comments on your question however, that this is not the best approach, and that you should be dealing with your DATA, and then use that DATA to populate the cells. Editing the cells displayed on screen is poor practice (and honestly it might not be possible to do what you want to do).